# Use JS Object to init Google Maps MapTypes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Got an JS object like this:

console.log(States)

```
Object {0: "SATELLITE", 1: "HYBRID"}
```

Now i need to push those two maptypes into options for google maps:

```
        var opt = {
          zoom: 15,     
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId[States], 'custom_style']
          }          
        };
```

This OFC this is not working. As you see i have a custom styled map also.

So i could do:

```
mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 'custom_style']
```

but it needs to be dynamic. The datastructure of "States" cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through `States` before you create your `opts` variable. Then create an array of `mapIds`, which you would then pass into your `mapTypeIds`.

```
var mapIds = []

for (var key in States) {
  mapIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[States[key]])
}

var opt = {
  zoom: 15,     
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: mapIds
  }          
};
```